# Where to find log file in sonatype nexus server,trough brew install on osx

Tags: homebrew, nexus

**I installed a sonatype nexus server through brew on mac Motion Lion as below:**

```
➜  ~  brew install nexus
==> Downloading http://download.sonatype.com/nexus/oss/nexus-2.6.3-01-bundle.tar

Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/nexus-2.6.3-01.tar.gz

==> Caveats

To have launchd, start nexus at login:

ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/nexus/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Then to load nexus now:

launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nexus.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:

/usr/local/opt/nexus/libexec/bin/nexus start

==> Summary

  /usr/local/Cellar/nexus/2.6.3-01: 285 files, 42M, built in 2 seconds

➜  ~  /usr/local/opt/nexus/libexec/bin/nexus start

Starting Nexus OSS...

Started Nexus OSS.
```

But I can’t find nexus server start ok, 8081 port is not started.

Where can I find the log file?

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party... For Nexus 3.15...

So, relative to your installation folder, for example if you copied the tar.gz to `/opt` and extracted it there, the full path is going to be:

```
/opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/log/
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where it is with the brew installer. Typically there is a sibling folder to the nexus folder called sonatype-work.

The nexus.log file is in sonatype-work/nexus/log

Worst case just look for a nexus.log file or start Nexus manually with

> ./bin/nexus console

and look at the log.

Comment: ➜  libexec git:(master) pwd


/usr/local/Cellar/nexus/2.6.3-01/libexec

➜  libexec git:(master) ls

LICENSE.txt bin         lib         wrapper.log

NOTICE.txt  conf        nexus

**thanks i just got it, wrapper.log**

Answer (score 0):

➜  libexec git:(master) pwd

/usr/local/Cellar/nexus/2.6.3-01/libexec

➜  libexec git:(master) ls

LICENSE.txt bin         lib         wrapper.log

NOTICE.txt  conf        nexus

**thanks i just got it, wrapper.log**